# preg_match_all error with \n (line break)

Tags: php, pattern-matching, preg-match-all

I have this pattern for preg_match_all: `/(<span[^>]*value=.?(\w*).?[^>]*annotation[^>]*>)(.*?)<\/span>/` that work for this text:

```
example<span id="Marky100120131906070" class="myMarkGen" value="247" name="annotation">logy.*-/+!\"·$%&/()=?¿hi </span>example
```

but this does not work in this case:

```
example<span id="Marky100120131906070" class="myMarkGen" value="247" name="annotation">logy.*-/+!\"

·$%&/()=?¿hi </span>example
```

Note that there is a line break

What is the pattern that would work in both cases, and that works regardless of the content of the span?I need the text in to span and the value of span

you can try it [here](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plus Modifiers it will do:

```
/(<span[^>]*value=.?(\w*).?[^>]*annotation[^>]*>)(.*?)<\/span>/smi
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! could you explain this /smi. what is its use?

Comment: @Martin See this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for an explanation.  Actually, I think you could just use the multilne (`m`) modifier, couldn't you?

Comment: @Martin You'll need the s modifier (If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded.), I prefer s+m,  When m is set, the "start of line" and "end of line" constructs match immediately following/before any newline in the subject string. i simply stands for ignore cases, so no matter if you've upper and lower case letters.